# помогите насторить доступ к mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Скачал сервер с [http://www.denwer.ru/].Не получается получить доступ к БД.
1 файл 1.php

```
<pre>
<?php
$db_host='test1.ru';
$db_database='test';
$db_username='root';
$db_password='YES';
?>
</pre>
```

Сама страница

```
<pre>
<?php
include('1.php');
// Подключиться к базе данных
$connection = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$connection) {
die("Невозможно подключиться к базе данных: <br />". mysql_error());
}
?>
</pre>
```

Помогите новичку.Выбила ошибка Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in J:hometest1.ruwwwindex.php on line 12
Невозможно подключиться к базе данных:
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

означает что вы используете неправильный пароль для подключения к бд

Answer (score 1):

```
define('BD_NAME','your_db');
.............................
mysql_select_db(BD_NAME,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
```